# Pattern matching existential goal in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I was wondering if there is a way to write the following pattern matching:

```
have "∃ q1 q2 q3 q4.
        b0^2 - a1^2 = 
            q1*(-1 + a0^2 + b0^2 - t^2 * a0^2 * b0^2) +
            q2*(-1 + a1^2 + b1^2 - t^2 * a1^2 * b1^2) +
            q3*(a0 * b0 - a1 * b1) +
            q4*(a1 * b0 + a0 * b1)"   
    (is "∃ q1 q2 q3 q4. ?a = ?b")
```

Currently I'm getting a pattern matching fail, I have the concern that this may not be possible in general...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write it like this, `?a` and `?b` are constants of type `bool`, i.e. they must not depend on `q1` to `q4`. Since, in your case, the statement depends on them, the pattern matching fails.

You have to write it as

```
(is "∃ q1 q2 q3 q4. ?a q1 q2 q3 q4 = ?b q1 q2 q3 q4")
```

and then it works.

Otherwise, what would `?a` be, used outside the existential quantifier? It would refer to variables `q1` to `q4` that are not bound anywhere.